# Is there a way to fetch build or jobs directory path in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, path, jobs

I have written a job in which I execute commands in shell script. Now jenkins provide some env variables like jenkins_home, workspace which when I echo get the respective path.
Is there a way to fetch build directory path or job directory path?
There is build_url and job_url but I need the absolute path, not the url. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you know where build directory is located, you can traverse from $workspace path.

Comment: Did you look at the $WORKSPACE variable?

Comment: That's the issue I don't know the build directory. I tried to traverse from workspace backwards to see iif I can find build directory but it seems they both have different paths

Comment: @Uberhumus: yes . I tried to traverse backwards so that I can find folder where builds are stored but no success

Comment: If you don't know where it's the build is happening, I suggest you SSH into the Jenkins Node while it is occurring, and use "lsof" to see where the files are.
It might be quite sisyphic but it could get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable 'WORKSPACE' will give you the absolute path to the folder where the build is happening.

If your build is a pipeline build you can:

```
sh("chmod +x /${WORKSPACE}/FolderWithScripts/ScriptName.sh && /${WORKSPACE}/FolderWithScripts/ScriptName.sh")
```

(chmod part is to ensure you have execute permissions)

[Here](https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables) is a list with environment variables available